# What exactly are the Operators and Operands in Halstead Metrics?

Tags: quality, metrics, code-metrics

Can anybody point me to the official source where it is explained what are operators and operands in Halstead Metrics for code, I would prefer the original paper by Halstead. Please don't post the Wikipedia link as anyone can edit the page. 
My original question is, let's say there is a function "fun" taking one value as an input. In an expression

```
x = a + fun(b)
```

Is fun an operator or an operand or both ?. "()" is one operator or "(" & ")" are different ?

Comment: `fun` is a unary operator. There are exceptions, such as if `fun` is a variable containing a function reference, then `fun` is an operand and `()` is an operator.

Comment: And why aren't you able to read the original paper, as it is cited in the wikipedia article?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the wikipedia article, it says functions called are operators.  This is because they do things — they are effectively user-defined operators, so each function that is called counts as an operator.

A function would count as an operand if it passed as a parameter or assigned to a variable, i.e. without being called in such constructs.

The `()` operate in pairs.  There is no countable meaning for `(` separate from `)` — so one count for a pair.